# Unable to read closed .xls file OLEDB

Tags: c#, .net, oledb

[Please feel free to mark it as duplicate if there is already an answer to this.]

I am facing some problem when reading an Excel (.xls) file using OLEDB.

My connection string is-

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";
```

Exception- `External table is not in the expected format.`

However this issue does not occur with .xlsx file using the below connection string-

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";
```

I found a similar question but there is no accepted answer to this-
[External table is not in the expected format when Excel file is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747655/external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format-when-excel-file-is-closed?rq=1)

Please let me know if any details needed.

Thanks,
Souvik

Comment: Have you tried this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521817/error-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format and also this one: http://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/

Comment: provide your sample code you have tried to read the file